# Web Scraping script with python returns always the same figure

Tags: python-3.x, web

I've just practiced a code from youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJqbTDhF8Ng) and for a reason I can't understand the fucntion does't update the price variable, returns always the same figure. Nevertheless on the website the value changes very often and quickly. What's wrong with it?

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time




url = "https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin"



def bitcoin_scraper():
    for n in range (1, 11):
        result = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs(result.content, "html.parser")

        price = soup.find("div", {"class":"price-large"})

        print(price.text)
        time.sleep(10)
    
bitcoin_scraper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine but the value on the page is updated AFTER the page loads (you can see it from browser with multiple reloads and checking the value after a few seconds).

If you really want your code to work perfectly you should put some wait state in order to have the page fully loaded (and its js executed) before you pull the data.
While this is doable it can lead to multiple issues / errors.

Why are you scraping if the same website offers a nice and free API?
I'd suggest you to use the API instead.

```
import requests

def get_bitcoin_value():
    url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
    resp = requests.get(url=url)
    data = resp.json()
    return(data['bpi']['USD']['rate'])

print(get_bitcoin_value())
```

Comment: Hi Pitto, many thanks. I understand the website offers a free API to that but I was exercising web scarping. I'm new to Python. The issue is solved, the problem was that every time after the first call the script was getting the figure from website cache in my browser. All the best

Comment: Hi there,

if you found my code useful please don't forget upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.